# How to style alternate table rows WITHOUT pseudo-classes, JS, or <tr> classes

Tags: html, css

I'm using an old online HTML editor/creator that does not allow me to insert pseudo-classes or JS.

I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to style alternate table rows without pseudo-classes and without assigning alternate table rows a class, nor the use of JS.

The reason for not giving alternate rows a specific class is that the content is editable by other administrator users, however they are not familiar with HTML, so I am creating a stylesheet that they can attach to their HTML documents.

**Any solutions using JS or pseudo-classes are immediately removed by this old HTML editor/creator system, and any solution that needs an understanding of HTML is not realizable.**

Below is a typical HTML table which **CANNOT** be edited (yes this includes JS)

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**The end result is for alternate rows to be of a different colour,** provided the way that this is accomplished **DOES NOT** include:

1. JS
2. Pseudo-classes
3. Knowledge of HTML (i.e. adding a class or style to alternate rows in HTML such as `<tr class="changeBGcolour">` or `<tr style="background-color:grey;">`)

I simply want to know if this can be achieved.

---

Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated,

Thank you.

P.S. I have no control over the text editor

Answer (score 3):

If you can assume a maximum length of table then you can just write your CSS out longform:

```
tr { background: grey; }
tr + tr { background: white; }
tr + tr + tr { background: grey; }
tr + tr + tr + tr { background: white; }
tr + tr + tr + tr + tr { background: grey; }
tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr { background: white; }
tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr { background: grey; }
…
```

This is going to slow down your CSS pretty quickly so don’t just chuck in 1000 of these to cope with every eventuality, but if you can assume say 20 rows max then it’s workable.

Comment: This solution does work, however I don't want to "chuck 1000 of these to cope with every eventuality" as you mentioned. I've upvoted your answer but I won't accept it as the answer yet. Someone else might have another idea.

Comment: To simplify things a bit, you could implement the idea using just two rules, with long lists of selectors: `tr, tr + tr + tr, tr + tr + tr + tr + tr,... { background: grey } tr + tr, tr + tr + tr + tr,... { background: white }`.

Comment: Yes, completely correct Jukka, that’s a better way.

Comment: ctwheels: I’m not sure there’s another way. If you’re relying on CSS and not JavaScript and you don’t have access to pseudoclasses then you’re limited to the [‘combinator’ selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#combinators), and the only two that deal with siblings are `+` and `~`. But I’ll be interested to see if anyone else has a curveball.